# in visual studio 2019, how to customise navigation bar in each view (not globally)

Tags: xamarin, navigation, visual-studio-2019

I want to customise navigation bar for one view (again, not globally, just for that one view). I have search on the internet and only found how to customise it globally from the app.xaml file.

I have tried to code as below in my view.xaml file

```
    <ContentPage.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <Style TargetType="NavigationPage">
                <Setter Property="BarBackgroundColor"
                        Value="{StaticResource blackColor}"/>
                <Setter Property="BarTextColor"
                        Value="{StaticResource whiteColor}"/>

            </Style>

        </ResourceDictionary>

    </ContentPage.Resources>
```

but it does not work unlike when I stylise other item such as entries/buttons

Comment: Use key and you are setting the style in the resource. Where as you have to set it to the Style property. I'll add an Answer to this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Regarding `Style` if `Key` is not set to a value, then style is applied to all the objects of the TargetType.

In your App.Xaml, set a Style with `x:Key`

```cs
<Style TargetType="ContentPage" x:Key="specialPage">
    <Setter Property="BackgroundColor" Value="Green"/>
</Style>
```

In your ContentPage page

```cs
<ContentPage
    xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
    Style="{StaticResource Key=specialPage}"
```

As you can see this style is for ContentPage as NavigationApp is set only once for an Application you could set the property of NavigationBar in ContentPage Style.

So,

1) You can keep the NavigationPage static and use the static variable to change the NavigationPage Property

**App.Xaml.cs**

```cs
public static App CurrentApplication;
public NavigationPage AppNavigationPage;

public App()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    CurrentApplication = this;
    this.AppNavigationPage = new NavigationPage(new MainPage());
    MainPage = this.AppNavigationPage;
}
```

Page.Xaml.cs

```cs
public Page1()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    App.CurrentApplication.AppNavigationPage.BarBackgroundColor = Color.Red;
}
```

2) Use Dynamic resource for styling the NavigationPage

Comment: when I write
CurrentApplication = this;
I got error saying "the name ... does not exist in the current context", am I missing something here?

Comment: Sorry my bad please check it now. Should add a Static variable for fetching it later in the App

Comment: no errors now but when I run it, it stops midway because AppNavigationPage is null. Why does this happen

Comment: Please change the code in MainPage from constructor to OnAppearing override method. This should do it.

Answer (score 0):

**NavigationPage.TitleView**
This tag will help you to customize your Navigation bar.